# Asymptotic distribution of L infinity norm of Gaussian random vector

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

Let $\mathbf{X}_n = (X_{n,1}, \ldots, X_{n,n})$ be a $n$-dimensional random vector with $N_n( \mathbf{0}_n, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_n )$ distribution. The asymptotic distribution of the $L_\infty$-norm of $\mathbf{X}_n$, i.e., $\| \mathbf{X}_n \|_\infty = \max_i\{ |X_{n,i}| \}$ as $n \to \infty$ can be derived using the Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem when $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_n = \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}_n$, where $\mathbf{I}_n$ denotes the identity matrix.

But, how to derive the asymptotic distribution for other structures of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_n$ as $n \to \infty$? I could not find appropriate results on this. Is convergence to a non-degenerate random variable (after suitable centering and scaling) guaranteed? If $\max_n\{ \sigma_{i,i} \} < \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\sigma_{i,i}$ denotes the $i$th diagonal element of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_n$, then intuitively I feel that the limiting centered and scaled distribution of $\| \mathbf{X}_n \|_\infty$ would be stochastically bounded. But, is convergence guaranteed in that case? What other conditions on $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_n$ except a diagonal structure would guarantee convergence to a non-degenerate distribution?